# JQuery: Retrieving a list of ids/Names by hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

How do I make a div(`<div id="HoverMe">`) hoverable, and display a list of names from `AllCarId`-list (by return `Car.Name` in place of `Car.Id`)?

- I got two tables `Owner(Id)` and `Car(Id, OwnerId, Name)`.
- I have a property `TotCar` in ViewModel where I use `Count()` in controller to add total `Car.OwnerId = Owner.Id` in `model.TotCar`.
- I also got  `public List<Guid> AllCarId { get; set; }`inside the ViewModel to pass `OwnerId` to list for every related `Owner.Id` = `Car.OwnerId`.

So far I got this where I currently show the count-value of `TotCar`:

```
<div id="HoverMe">    
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotCar)  
</div>

@*I want this to be hoverable and list all from AllCarId(convert to name) in a "listbox"*@
```

So how do I make `<div id="HoverMe">` hoverable, once it hovers, list every items in `AllCarId`?

This is how I pass `id`'s to `AllCarId` in Controller.

```
List<Guid> GetCarIds = db.Cars.Where(c => c.OwnerId == id).Select(c=> c.OwnerId).ToList();
```

Then I pass `GetCarIds` to model `public List<Guid> AllCarId { get; set; }` property.

**EDIT: related property from models:**

ViewModel:

```
  public List<Guid> AllCarId { get; set; }
  public int TotCar { get; set; }       
  public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
```

Car:

```
  public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
  public System.Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
```

Owner:

```
public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is just as unclear as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926353/possible-to-read-database-inside-view-with-jquery-and-display). [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried it improve it, not sure what's missing. Is there anything specifics you can point out what's unclear?

Comment: You could start by showing the model that you use in the view. And what do you mean _list all from AllCarId(convert to name)_? And what is the purpose of the ListBox (are you trying to select some values, and if so what is the property that you bind the selected values to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the model. By that, I mean you hover the div, then a list should appear and list every item from `AllCarId` ( return `Car.Name` in place of `Car.Id` instead if possible)

Comment: What is `AllCarId` (thats not in your view model). And are you wanting to display the `Name` property of `Car`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh I added `AllCarId ` now. Yes I do.

Comment: Instead of storing `List<Guid> AllCarId{get;set;}`, create a model class `CarModel` with `Id` and `Name` and make `List<CarModel> AllCars{get;set;}` , then you can access the name on your view

Comment: Still not clear. Why does your model have a property `Car` (single) when you seen to wanting multiple cars in the view. You can simply change the property to `IEnumerable<string> Cars` and populate it using `model.Cars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.OwnerId == id).Select(c=> c.Name);` in the controller. Then you can render the car names in the view in a hidden element, and use javascript to display it in the `hover` event

Comment: @StephenMuecke Got it. But I'm not sure how to do that(render car names in a hidden element) ?

Comment: `<div id="cars">@foreach(var car in Model.Cars) { <div>@car</div> }</div>` and use css to style it `#cars { display: none; }` Then you could use [jQuery.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to toggle its visibility